# Spring Boot create Database from entites with hibernate dont work

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate

im created entities and want to create a embedded h2 database with tables and columns from this entities.

Thats my application.yml file:
[image]

intellij logs the correct sql statements from hibernate (so it runs atleast):
[image]

but my connected database shows empty in intellij:

[image]

what do i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are using an im-memory database.

That means if you "connect" from the application you have a different database as when you "connect" from Intellij.

Comment: In springboot (default) we can overcome! Logs print (devtools!? H2 console!) a (uuid-based) jdbc url, which points exactly to the used db instance..